# Angular2 - getting a TemplateRef inside a service

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Is there a way to get a TemplateRef for an existing html template inside a service?

Context of the question (since I may be doing something wrong in the first place):

I'm creating a service which uses [NgbModal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) to display some text in a popup. The modal requires a TemplateRef to display the contents, which I don't exactly know how to create. The other options are to pass a string (which is escaped, and I need to display html) or to pass a component (which I don't know how to pass the desired text to).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways

- `<template>` from the components template:
- `<template>` passed as child from the outside

(not tested)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  template: '<template #ref1>xxx</template>'
})
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('ref1') template1:TemplateRef;

  constructor(private template2:TemplateRef, private someService:SomeService) {
    someService.template2 = template2;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.someService.template1 = this.template1;
  }
}
```

```
<foo><template>yyy</template>
```

Comment: Will try that, but it makes a kind of circular dependency: the component needs the service, but the service needs the component to inject the template, otherwise it will not be properly set up. Could there be a way to avoid that?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm pretty sure you need a component to get a reference. I wouldn't worry about the circular here. It's only bi-directional. The service has to wait for the component to pass the reference, but otherwise I don't see an issue here.

Comment: I see that's the way to go then. Will try that out, thanks.